# including urls of one app into urls file of another app in django

Tags: python, django, url

I have two apps in my project, institute and students. I have included the urls of institute app in root url file.

**root urls.py**

```
urlpatterns += [    
    url(r'^insti/', include('institute.urls', namespace='institute')), 
]
```

**institute/urls.py file**

```
from institute import views
from django.conf.urls import url, include

app_name = "institute"
# institute urls
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.institute_home, name='home'),
    url(r'^signin/$', views.signin, name='signin'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.institute_logout, name='logout'),
    # other urls here
]
# students urls in institute
urlpatterns += [    
    url(r'^student/', include('students.urls', namespace='students')),
]
```

**students/urls.py file**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from students import views

app_name = "students"
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.students_home, name="students_home"),
    url(r'^register/$', views.register, name="register"),
    url(r'^signin/$', views.signin, name="signin"),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.students_logout, name="logout"),
    # other urls
]
```

When I am hitting urls like `localhost/insti/sigin, localhost/insti/<anything>` it works fine, but as soon as I hit the url `localhost/insti/students` it throws me error

> 'students' is not a registered namespace

somewhere in my code at line  `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("students:signin"))`

Is the way I am including students urls in institute's url is wrong or there is some other issue?

Comment: student app doesnt have an url sign in, wont in the template it will be institute:signin

Comment: It have signin url. I omitted it. including it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way to procede is :

*root urls.py*

```
urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^insti/student/', include('students.urls', namespace='students')),
    url(r'^insti/', include('institute.urls', namespace='institute')),
]
```

So you can use `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("students:signin"))`.

If you dont want to change your urls organisation, use this :

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("institue:students:signin"))
```

Comment: I am using return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("institue:students:signin")) and it worked.